# SqlException: Cannot open database <database> requested by the login. The login failed

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, visual-studio, database-connection

I am developing an application in C# using Visual Studio 2013 and want to connect to my database.
I've attempted to do this the code and connection string below.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "server=.;database=[Demo Database Nav (5-0)];user=us;password=id";
```

I get the error message:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Servern kunde inte behandla begäran. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "[Demo Database Nav (5-0)]" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'us'.

I have opened SQL Server and added the login 'us' with the password 'id'. I have made this login a db_owner and associated it with the right Database. I have tried  this with several logins but none of them have worked. Is there something wrong with my connection string?

Comment: are you able to login manually from management studio?

Comment: try this for connection https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: Just a tip, you might want to consider using the SqlConnectionStringBuilder class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have developed a lot of C# application that connects to SQL Server 2005/2008 database, and my connection strings are:

```
Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=<database>; Integrated Security=SSPI
```

for local databases

```
Data Source=<ip address>\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=<database>; Integrated Security=FALSE; User ID=<user>; password=<password>
```

for remote databases

Just fill all "<>" fields with the correct values.

Answer (score 2):

Create an empty text file on desktop, name it with a `.udl` extension. Once created, double-click on it and you will see a GUI open up to guide you through to build the connection string. Step through it and click on **test connection** if successful then open the udl file up in a text editor and copy the `connectionstring` and paste it in your code

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Database=[Demo Database Nav (5-0)];User Id=userhere;Password=passhere";
```

It seems like the user property doesn't have "Id" like "User Id"

Regards.